# Looks like binder for date works incorrect in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-binding

[image]

I have startdate in QueryString with value: 3/1/2012

DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString["startdate"]).Month return month number: 1

but in my controller i have action Index(DateTime startDate) and startDate.Month return 3

Is anybody can explain why bind of date doesnt work as expected?

btw, i have culture in web.config already:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default model binder **always** uses InvarianCulture when parsing query string values, no matter which culture you configured in your web.config.

- GET => InvariantCulture
- POST => culture agnostic

So assuming you have the 2 actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Foo(DateTime date)
{
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Bar(DateTime date)
{
    ...
}
```

when you invoke the Foo action you should always use the invariant culture to format the date in the query string, whereas when you invoke the Bar action and pass the date parameter in the POST body payload, the default model binder will use the culture configured in your web.config.

Take a look at the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx) which covers this in more details.

Comment: ok, but why model binder return 3 in month property even if im using: dd/mm/yyyy ?

Comment: Because in InvariantCulture the short date format is `MM/dd/yyyy` and as I explained in my answer when you use a GET request the default model binder uses invariant culture.

Comment: @msony Then you have two options. Change it so you are formatting the date as Invariant Culture, or write your own model binder.