# POST call throws null exception while GET doesn't

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I'm using $.ajax() to send a post call to the server. If I use POST for type, it gives an error, but if I do it with GET it works perfectly.

The problem is that when doing POST, the parameter `unitTotal` is null on the server-side. But when doing GET that parameter is correctly passed.

Here's the ajax code:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",

    url: '/Sepet/SepeteTabloEkle',

    data: { "tabloId": tabloId, "en": en, "boy": boy, "accessoryIds": accessoryIds, "miscTypes": miscTypes, "unitTotal": total },

    traditional:true,

    success: function (data) {
    },
});
```

Here's my action definition:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SepeteTabloEkle(int tabloId, int en, int boy, List<int> accessoryIds, List<string> miscTypes, decimal unitTotal )
```

And here's the error the server gives if I use POST. If I use GET this error is not thrown and `unitTotal` gets passed nicely.

The error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'unitTotal' of non-nullable type 'System.Decimal' for method 'Void
>   SepeteTabloEkle(Int32, Int32, Int32,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32],
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String], System.Decimal)' in
>   'RenkliTablo.Controllers.SepetController'. An optional parameter must
>   be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>
> ### parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Comment: why can't you use get?..

Comment: because that's what he *should* be using to "post" data to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of a difference in the culture from the client and the server. When using GET request the default model binder always uses `InvariantCulture` to parse query string parameters into their underlying types as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9977290/29407). When using POST the model binder uses the current culture. So if you are using a culture on the server where the decimal separator is `,` and not `.` the POST request fails.

Comment: I understand your answer now, after several days

Answer (score 0):

Take away the `traditional: true` setting.

> [data is] appended to the url for GET-requests. ... Object must be Key/Value pairs. If
>   value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
>   based on the value of the traditional setting

Comment: If in the action I take the parameter as string rather than decimal, to parse it to decimal later, it works. Using POST with traditional:true setting