# DateTime Format In Model Binding

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, cultureinfo, asp.net-web-api2

In my Web API project I have following model:

```
public class ModelClass
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date Cannot Be Empty", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Date Not In Correct Date Format")]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

which is being utilized in following action:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Submit([FromUri] ModelClass model)
{
 //do sth
}
```

Now if I pass date like `localhost:3647/api/Controller/Submit?date=31/12/2015` `ModelState` validation fails for `DataType` even though I changed globalization to match the date format of `dd/MM/yyyy` like below:

```
<globalization culture="ms-MY" uiCulture="ms-MY" />
```

Comment: Obligitory: http://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC as I known query string are always parsed using InvariantCulture.
Only POST body are parsed using Thread Culture. I think that this is to allow to create urls that are valid for all users.

Look also at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9977290/209727

Or this blog post: http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization

If you really need to use this format maybe you can just use a string and parse it inside your controller?